# Is there any recourse for a user who is being harassed by another user?

Tags: support, closed-questions

If I feel like a certain user is harassing me, editing my answers, downvoting my answers, closing my questions, making offensive and condescending comments, or anything like that; what can I do? I have read the relevant FAQs:

[Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators)

[Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions)

[What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions)

But what I am asking about is a specific person who seems to be "following me around" the site. I only have one answer and one (closed) question on Programmers.SE, and both of them have positive reputation and upvotes, apart from this single user who is consistently harassing me. Is there something I can do to report that?

Comment: although, this might not be a bad question because I've seen at least one occasion in the past where this did happen, you can rest assured that in your particular case nobody is "following you around".  2 posts isn't enough data points to draw any useful conclusions.  What you saw is simply an active senior member who put its in a lot of his own time in moderating this site. Did you see the edits he made? Was it vandalism because he was out to get you? Or did he just make minor grammatical corrections because your post had grammatical errors?

Comment: Don't assume that because a particular user took a constructive action on your post (ie an edit) that the _same user_ also took negative action against your post.  Votes are anonymous by design.  For example, there are currently 704 views on your question.  There are 6 up votes and 3 down votes to your question.  _Almost any_ of those 704 views could have resulted in the up and down votes.  You have absolutely no way of attributing them.  Likewise with the 1400+ views to the question you answered.  You simply don't know who did what and nor should you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since he treats everyone that way, and doesn't single out individuals, that somehow makes it no longer harassment, and makes it "conscientiously improving the quality of the site."  Unfortunately, there is no real policy in place to deal with over-zealousness, despite its affect on the site's image with new users.  You are not the first person to describe the end effect of this particular user's voting and editing patterns as feeling "harassed."

What you *can* do is dispute individual edits or closings, either with a meta post, or by raising a flag.  For example, I think you have a pretty strong case that [Stacking keywords on top of each other - poor style?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/221710/3965) is an example of a "[good subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)" question, and I voted to reopen accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Claims of harassment are beyond the scope of moderator authority. If you feel that you are being harassed, please contact the [Community Team](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) either through the link I have provided or the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of every page.